# Trying import table from mysql using sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, import, hdfs, sqoop

Here I am trying to import database from mysql using sqoop. When I am trying I am getting below error. Can any one please help me

```
[root@sandbox ~]# sqoop import-all-tables -m 12 --connect     "jdbc:mysql://sandbox.hortonworks.com:3306/retail_db" --username=retail_dba -P --             as-avrodatafile --warehouse-dir=/apps/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will    fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/05/22 16:12:48 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.0.0-169
Enter password:
16/05/22 16:12:52 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL     streaming resultset.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/lib/slf4j-     log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-    log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an     explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/05/22 16:12:53 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/05/22 16:12:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT     t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/05/22 16:12:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT     t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/05/22 16:12:53 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is     /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-    root/compile/9a872a9731ab3cb2920a1910153051ff/categories.java uses or overrides a     deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/05/22 16:12:58 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-    root/compile/9a872a9731ab3cb2920a1910153051ff/categories.jar
16/05/22 16:12:58 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing     from mysql.
16/05/22 16:12:58 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use     the --direct
16/05/22 16:12:58 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-    specific fast path.
16/05/22 16:12:58 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
16/05/22 16:12:58 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of     categories
16/05/22 16:13:01 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT     t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/05/22 16:13:01 INFO mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob: Writing Avro schema      file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/9a872a9731ab3cb2920a1910153051ff/ca             tegories.avsc
16/05/22 16:13:02 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address:     http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/05/22 16:13:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at      sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.0.4:8050
16/05/22 16:13:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:     sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.0.4:8050. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy              is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000     MILLISECONDS)
16/05/22 16:13:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:     sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.0.4:8050. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy              is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000     MILLISECONDS)
16/05/22 16:13:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:     sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.0.4:8050. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy              is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000     MILLISECONDS)
16/05/22 16:13:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:     sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.0.4:8050. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy              is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000     MILLISECONDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some issue with NameNode.

Kindly check namenode logs in $HADOOP_HOME/logs/namenode.log

Check is hadoop is up at http://localhost:50070

Comment: I just restarted virtual machine in azure and then it works correctly. Thank you for your response.